# How to install Wordpress on IIS at root directory(wwwroot)?

Tags: iis, wordpress

I've been trying to install Wordpress using Web PI. However, when I complete installation with default configuration, it is always installed at ://localhost/wordpress, which is inetpub/wwwroot/wordpress. I plan to install it once again. How can I configure it so that it installs at http://localhost instead of ://localhost/wordpress? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Has WebPI installed webmatrix as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually move wordpress to any folder. If you move the files into wwwroot, then continue with setup as normal by editing wp-config.php and then installing with http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php